# Why Doesn't CLU Visit Flynn Earlier?

Tags: plot-explanation, tron-legacy

In [Tron : Legacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron%3a_Legacy), When Quorra initially rescues Sam she tells him that Rinzler and co. can't follow them off the grid. But then when Quorra and the Fylnns go back into grid city, CLU and his cronies show up at Flynn's house.

It seems like Quorra meant that they couldn't go off the grid via land vehicles, so assuming that is the case, how did CLU suddenly know where Flynn was hiding out? Why didn't he just go there many cycles ago with a small army and get Flynn's disc?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

CLU discovers Flynn's hideout by tracing the signature left behind by Sam when he takes his father's retro-lightcycle into the 'city'. The elder Flynn actually berates his son for this mistake when he catches up with him.

As for why CLU didn't try to get him many cycles ago, the limitations of their vehicles, plus the 'hidden entrance' of Flynn's hideout (recall the scene when Quorra seemingly drives through a rock face) must have kept CLU at bay all this time.

Comment: Okay must have missed that detail. But couldn't he have still traced Quorra's signature since it would seem like she had visited many times apart from the rescue. Not sure that I buy the hidden entrance part and it doesn't seem so hidden since it directly looks into the city and therefore it would be an obvious light source coming from the mountains.

Comment: You make a couple of good points. I was referring more to the 'rear entrance' to Flynn's hideout in my answer, but the large, glowing plateau is a bit of an elephant in the room. I guess one could say that Flynn's ability to shape the grid and the landscape at whim could turn it into a sort of 'one-way-mirror', but at this point trying to justify the innumerable inconsistencies in this film is like trying to plug a sinking ship with jell-o :)

Answer (score 3):

The question isn't exactly accurate. Quorra didn't say they couldn't go off the grid - just that they could not follow them. When she rescues Sam, they jump the vehicle across a canyon and switch the vehicle into all-terrain mode. The light cycles that were used in the games could not follow them or make the jump, but CLU has no problem traveling into the badlands or other parts of the grid.

Flynn was not hiding off the grid. He was hiding in the badlands which was outside the city. CLU didn't know where Flynn was because he disappeared after the war. Staying in his hideout, his approach to fighting CLU was to do nothing.

Had CLU known about Flynn's whereabouts he would have gone there and forcefully taken Flynn's disk (but he could not kill him, as the two were the same). Since Flynn had disappeared, CLU tricked Sam into entering the grid in order to get Flynn to expose himself.

CLU was able to trace the light cycle back to the hideout, because light cycles leave a trail behind them. It's this trail that is used to create a wall of glass in the games. Had Sam used a different vehicle then maybe CLU wouldn't have been able to retrace its path.

Answer (score 0):

Er... The programs trace the light cycle back from its original location. I'm assuming that the bike has some kind of GPS system which explains why sam was able to find Zeus so easily.